# Retrieving the text parts of a xpath node() value

Tags: xml, xpath

I've created an xpath expression as follows:

```
/html/body/div[2]/div/ul[2]/li/a/node()
```

It returns something like this:

```
#01 <strong>value</strong> suffix
```

How do I extract the "#01" part and the "suffix" part in two different xpath expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you'd get the 'strong' node then use previous-sibling and following-sibling axes

```
/html/body/div[2]/div/ul[2]/li/a/strong/previous-sibling::node()
/html/body/div[2]/div/ul[2]/li/a/strong/following-sibling::node()
```

Might not be absolutely right - bit rusty on xpath!

Comment: text()[following-sibling::strong] and text()[preceding-sibling::strong] worked, thanks